# New Browser window in Windows Phone with Phonegap/Jquery Mobile

Tags: windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile, cordova

How to open new Browser window in Windows Phone with Phonegap and Jquery Mobile?

I tried everything i could think of:

1. link name
2. With javscript window.open
3. etc

I can't get it to open in a new window. The problem is when it opens now it its inside the "webview" and when pressing the back button the application closes, it should go back to the prev page. Or it should open in a new window/outside the app (aka internet explorer).

There 2 possible solutions:

1. A way to open it outside the application
2. Open it inside but should be able to get back to the prev bage with the back button

Comment: Given Windows Phone doesn't really have a concept of "windows", what do you need it to do? Open in a new tab?

Comment: Open the url you click in my application in internet explorer instead of in the application itself.